# VBA Pass argument with .Onaction with parameter

Tags: vba

I've read other articles on this topic and their proposed solution is not working for me:

```
Sub doStuff()

    Dim x As String
    x = "hello"
    Sheets("sheet2").Shapes(1).OnAction = "'testIt " & x & "'"

End Sub

Sub testIt(something As String)

End Sub
```

When I click on Shapes(1) in sheet2, I get the following error response:
`Cannot run macro "testIt hello". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled`

I've tested this with other code that does not require a parameter, and it worked. It would simply read something like: `Sheets("sheet2").Shapes(1).OnAction = "someOtherMacro"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needs quotes around the argument:

```
Sheets("sheet2").Shapes(1).OnAction = "'testIt """ & x & """'"
```

Comment: A thousand blessings for you, Tim.